# Help with Plateau's Laws

Tags: geometry, surfaces, minimal-surfaces

Can someone please explain **mathematically** what is meant by the term 'smooth' in Plateau's First Law:

"Soap films are made of entire *smooth* surfaces"

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Differentiable manifold? You may find this useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_surfaces

Comment: "Smooth" in differential geometry is a shortcut for "differentiable any amount of times"